# How to append a new column to my Pandas DataFrame based on a row-based calculation?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Let's say I have a Pandas DataFrame with two columns: 1) user_id, 2) steps (which contains the number of steps on the given date). Now I want to calculate the difference between the number of steps and the number of steps in the preceding measurement (measurements are guaranteed to be in order within my DataFrame).

So basically this comes down to appending an extra column to my DataFrame where the row values of this data frame match the value of the column 'steps' within this same row, minus the value of the 'steps' column in the row above (or 0 if this is the first row). To complicate things further, I want to calculate these differences per user_id, so I want to make sure that I do not subtract the steps values of two rows with different user_id's.

Does anyone have an idea how to get this done with Python 2.7 and Panda?

So an example to illustrate this.

Example input:

```
user_id     steps
   1015       48
   1015       23
   1015       79
   1016       10
   1016       20
```

Desired output:

```
user_id     steps    d_steps
   1015       48          0
   1015       23        -25
   1015       79         56
   2023       10          0
   2023       20         10
```

Comment: It usually helps to give a specific example with input and desired output that people can copy and paste, rather than relying on description.

Comment: Agreed! I added an example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output shows user ids that are not in you orig data but the following does what you want, you will have to replace/fill the `NaN` values with 0:

```
In [16]:

df['d_steps'] = df.groupby('user_id').transform('diff')
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df
Out[16]:
   user_id  steps  d_steps
0     1015     48        0
1     1015     23      -25
2     1015     79       56
3     1016     10        0
4     1016     20       10
```

Here we generate the desired column by calling [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) on the groupby by object and pass a string which maps to the [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff) method which subtracts the previous row value. Transform applies a function and returns a series with an index aligned to the df.